# What is the difference between `reprintof` and `reprintfrom` in Biblatex' `relatedtype` tag?

Tags: biblatex

Biblatex allows a BibTeX entry to be `related` to another BibTeX entry, and the `relatedtype` tag can specify that one is a `reprintof` or a `reprintfrom` that entry, among other possibilities.

When should I use `reprintof` and when `reprintfrom`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `reprintof` if the reprint is of the whole thing referenced e.g. an article reprinted in a collection or anthology, originally published in a journal.

I would use `reprintfrom` if the reprint was of part of the original e.g. a chapter from a book reprinted as a standalone work.

Comment: It might be worth noting that with standard definitions `reprintfrom` uses the format `related:reprintfrom` while `reprintof` just uses the default.